# Fixed hight and width for a column table

Tags: html, css

I have a table with multiple column, two of them are being displayed not the way they should be. In fact I want the content to fit the column.

this is my code

```
<tr> 
    <td>
       <a style="display: block" href="../workitem/view.asp?item_id=<%=workItemId%>&hometoURL=<%=Server.URLEncode(navpath & "/de/ticket/liste_ticket_pl.asp")%>"><%=Workitem%></a>
    </td>
    <td background="../../images/white-dot.gif">
        <img src="../../images/white-dot.gif" width="1" height="8">
    </td>
    <td>
        <%=WorkitemRecordset.fields("Workitem_Rel")%>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What i get is , when my href is  short , the Workitem_Rel is positioned at left , and when href is long it's positioned in the right.

EDIT : this what I get

col1    col2

----- |-------

### text  | text

long text  |text 
           |

Comment: Try to make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably from the  of the head. Fix there the width/height

Comment: that was exactly the problem.Now fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```
table td {
   width: 30px;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: inline-block;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

Comment: @kryptong do you want to fix the width of tr?

Comment: What I want is that my column have the same width for all rows undependetly of the length of the content

Comment: then please make a fiddle for that .So i can clearly understand the problem.

Comment: it was all because of a colspan, so what I did is delete the table with colspan that was merged into another table and made simple columns